# Unable to run app on iPhone simulator or device

Tags: ios, xcode4

I submitted my app to the App Store yesterday; everything ran as it should.  This morning, I upgraded Java, (not sure this has anything to do with the issue, just thought I would mention it).  Now, I can't run my app in XCode 4 on any simulator or iPhone!

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

I have looked at all of the Google and SO issues dealing with this; most are involved with OS x.  This is only happening on iOS.  My iPhone is iOS 5.1, as is the simulator.  I have all settings for target OS set to 5.0.  I am running XCode 4.4.1.  I tried a different app, and it runs, no problems.

Anybody have any suggestions of what else to look at to fix this?

Comment: Tried changing compiler? LLVM And GCC.

Comment: Yikes, I have just accepted the Java update - praying this wont mess up my system as it did with yours.

Comment: I don't think it's the Java code, since I ran another app that uses the iPad simulator.  I did not try changing the compiler.  What I did do however, was make a new app, and copied all of the files to the new app.  Works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a new app, with just bare bones files in it (main.m, info.plist and Prefix.pch).  Then I copied the existing files (with the exception of the 3 files above) from the app which wasn't working, and it now runs just fine.